# How do you calculate the velocity of the pencil?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I'm drawing a quarter circle with a pencil on a sheet of graph paper. The radius is 10cm. At a given moment in time the velocity at which I am moving the pencil is 5cm/s (centimeters per second). I need to calculate the velocity of the pencil on the x and y axis of the paper at that moment in time.

What is the mathematical equation that is used to solve this type of problem?

[EDIT] I realize that the answer depends on how far along the curve the pencil is. Let's say that it is 25% of the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed, not velocity of the pencil is constant at $5$ cm/sec.  Velocity is a vector and has a direction, speed is the magnitude of velocity.  In general, the slope of the curve is given by the derivative.  Through a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the curve, the slope is $m=\frac {dy}{dx}|_{(x_0,y_0)}$ and the tangent line is $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$.  Then a vector along the tangent is $(1,m)$ (of length $\sqrt{1+m^2}$)and we can make it of length $L$ by multiplying by $\frac L{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$ to get $(\frac L{\sqrt{1+m^2}},\frac {mL}{\sqrt{1+m^2}})$

In the case of a circle of radius $10$ centered at the origin, the equation of the top half is $y=\sqrt{100-x^2}$ so $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {-x}{\sqrt{100-x^2}}$.  If we want the velocity at $(8,6)$ we have $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {-8}{\sqrt{100-64}}=-\frac 43$.  The vector along the tangent is then $(-1,\frac 43)$ (note we have to resolve the direction, I assume you are drawing counterclockwise), the length of that vector is $\sqrt{1+\frac {16}9}=\frac 53$, so the velocity is $\dfrac 5{\frac 53}(-1,\frac 43)=(-3,4)$

Comment: Yes, the arc would be to the top left of the origin, drawing CCW.

Comment: @kurtnelle:  I followed mathematical practice of having $+x$ to the right and $+y$ up, but in fact all that matters is that you are following the circle from $+x$ to $+y$ in the $+y$ half-plane.

Comment: would this problem fall under derivatives?

Comment: @kurtnelle:   Specifically for the circle, you can use the fact that the tangent is perpendicular to the radius to avoid them.  If you are at $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ you are moving in direction $(-\sin \theta,\cos theta)$ so your velocity is $(-s\sin \theta,s\cos theta)$ where $s$ is the speed.  You need the derivative unless you can find a nice geometric way to get the tangent.

Comment: Where did you get 5 over 5 over 3?

Comment: @kurtnelle:  I am scaling the vector to the desired length of $5$.  The current length is $\frac 53$ as shown in the sentence before.  So I divide by $\frac 53$ to get a unit vector and multiply by $5$

Comment: Why 5 and not 4?

Comment: @kurtnelle:  because you asked for a speed of $5$

Comment: so then the value (-3,4) is (-3 cm/s, 4 cm/s), and the 5 in this case brings them to the correct units?

Comment: @kurtnelle:  Yes.  When I divided by $\frac 53$ I normalized the vector, so it has no units at that point.  It wouldn't change if you asked for the result in m/sec.  Then we multiply by the desired speed, in your case 5 cm/sec.  If you had asked for 0.05 m/sec I would have multiplied by that, getting $(-0.03 m/s, 0.04 m/sec)$